# Asymmetric color scale with colorRampPalette in R

Tags: r, spatial, colorbar

I have a problem to fill my color bar scale. Since my values are not in symmetrical from -85 to 15 with interval 5, I want to have red color for the positive values and blue color for the negative values. Here is my code that I use:

```
brks <-seq(-85,15,5)
length(brks)
#Temperature
colorscale <- rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"))(length(brks)-1))
windows()
image.plot(x=lon, y=lat,inputvar,
           xlim=c(12,25),ylim=c(44,50),
           col=colorscale,breaks=brks,lab.breaks=brks,
           xlab="Longitude (deg)", ylab="Latitude (deg)")
title(main="Annual Bias Difference Summer Days")
mtext("Actual Difference (days)", side=4, adj=0.5,line=0.4)
map(database="world",add=TRUE)
# make grid lines
abline(h=seq(44,50,1), v=seq(12,24,2),lty=2,col="grey",lwd=0.5)
```

Here is my current plot :
[image: Asymmetric color scale]

I hope you can explain for me using the colorRampPalette because i need to use this function.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add `bias=2.74` to your `colorRampPalette()` call.  So:

```
colorscale <- rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"), bias=2.74)(length(brks)-1))
```

Bias changes the centre of the scale.  To work out how much bias to use I had a look at the code for `colorRamp`.  The only place it uses `bias` is in the line below where it works out the linear combination for interpolating the colours.

```
x <- seq.int(0, 1, length.out = nc)^bias
```

Since you want to map the halfway point on your scale to 0.15 of the way along it, you need `x=log(0.15)/log(0.5)=2.74`

I didn't have your data but here's an example of the outcome with ggplot:

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you! can u explain to me more to get this bias number?
For example I have 21 color breaks :
brks <-seq(-85,15,5)
so i will have 20 color boxes. Top 3 boxes will be colored by red (0 to 15), while the rest will be blue. How i determine the bias? Thank you

Comment: If you want 15% of your scale on one side and 85% on the other, then the bias `x` needs to be calculated so that `0.5^x = 0.15`.  You can solve this to get `x=2.74`.  It doesn't matter how many boxes you have.

Comment: Hey its working perfect. Just wanna ask, how to increase the font size of the scales? thx

Comment: This page might help.. https://statisticsglobe.com/increase-font-size-in-plot-in-r.  By the way if you're happy with the answer to your question you can 'accept' it.

Comment: Hey! I mean , i am using image.plot (), so usual way it doesnt work

Comment: try running (for example) `par(cex.axis=1.5)` before you run your `image.plot` command.