# How to set central color in a diverging color scheme at zero in a fvisgam plot?

Tags: r, plot, colors, gam, contourf

I am creating an `fvisgam` contour plot that displays a range of fitted values from -1 to 0.2, using the `RdBu` color palette [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7lSO.png). However, I would like the color white to represent the zero value in the diverging color palette, but currently, white represents the fitted value of -0.4. How can I specify this?

Here is a link to the dataset I have used for this plot: https://github.com/kmbarn4/stackoverflow_question/blob/main/10x10_vaed_c_est_vs_coverage-table.csv

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(colorspace)
library(mgcv)
library(itsadug)
library("viridis")
library("RColorBrewer")

m1 <- gam(relative_spn_median  ~ te(c_est, v.coverage), data=est_vaed10, family="gaussian")
color_palette <- rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"))
fvisgam(m1, view=c("c_est", "v.coverage"), color = color_palette, main="fvisgam plot", n.seg=2)
```

Comment: Can you include a reproducible example, e.g. add a sample of your data using `dput()` or use a built-in data set? Can you also list which packages you're using as it makes it much easier for others to help?

Comment: Hi Nrennie- thanks for your help! I've added a URL to the data file on github and the packages I used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by playing with `bias` from `colorRampPalette` to change the center of the scale, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74905034/asymmetric-color-scale-with-colorramppalette-in-r)?

```
# fvisgam plot, scale NOT centered on zero
m1 <- gam(relative_spn_median  ~ te(c_est, v.coverage), data=est_vaed10, family="gaussian")
color_palette <- rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"))
fvisgam(m1, view=c("c_est", "v.coverage"), color = color_palette, main="fvisgam plot with scale\nNOT centered on zero", n.grid = 100)

# fvisgam plot, scale centered on zero using bias
fv.min <- min(m1[["fitted.values"]])
fv.max <- max(m1[["fitted.values"]])
brks <- seq(fv.min, fv.max, 0.00001)
bias <- log(fv.max/(fv.max - fv.min))/log(0.5)
color_palette_on_zero <- rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"), bias=bias) (length(brks)-1))
fvisgam(m1, view=c("c_est", "v.coverage"), color = color_palette_on_zero, main="fvisgam plot with scale\ncentered on zero", n.grid = 100)
```

[image]